# Session Save Path issue in php

Tags: php, session

I have tried the following code in my index.php but still no luck

```
session_save_path('/home/domainName/tmp/sessions');
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
```

It is still shows session.save_path as no value in phpinfo()

Can anyone pls help me out what else needs to be done in order make session variable work on live server.

Answer (score 0):

You should alter those values in your `php.ini` file, as when you set them on runtime, the next request the initial values are used again (from `php.ini`), and thus in the output of `phpinfo()` it will not show up.

Answer (score 0):

If session_save_path does not work, you could try to work with ini_set:

```
ini_set('session.save_path',$path);
session_start();
```

This way you overwrite the **config value of PHP** just for this application and not in general, like the solution of giorgio. If you want to set it for all applications of the server, I would also suggest like giorgio to alter the "**php.ini**".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ini_set(session.save_path, '/home/domainName/tmp/sessions');
session_start();
```